# Norm of Hardy operator

Tags: functional-analysis

Consider operator: $$(Ax)(t) = \frac{1}{t}\int_{0}^{t}x(s)ds$$
I'm trying to prove that the operator $A$ maps continuous functions to continuous ones and $\|A\|_{ B(C[0,1])} = 1$ (in this case we set $(Ax)(0):= x(0)$). However, I'm unable to get the desired result, can somebody help me? Thank you!

Comment: Hint: what is the spectra?

Comment: $|Ax(t)|\leq\|x\|_\infty$ for all $t>0$ and this for $t=0$ as well. For $x\equiv1$, $Ax\equiv 1$.

Comment: To prove that $A$ maps continuous functions to continuous functions you can use de L'Hospital: $$\lim_{t \to 0+} \frac{1}{t}\int_0^t x(s) ds = \lim_{t \to 0+} \frac{x(t)}{1}=x(0).$$